# How can I enable colours in ZSH for root user?

Tags: shell, zsh, prompt, macos

I'm trying to move from Bash to ZSH, whichc is the new default shell on Mac OS Catalina. I have some bash settings in my profile, and I'd like to translate these settings into the ZSH, including my prompt. I managed to make a replica of my old prompt in the ZSH style, but every time I switch to root user, the prompt is black and white. Actually, the whole thing seems to be ignored and there are no colours at all. What am I doing wrong?

My `.zshrc` has the following:

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced
```

...which should allow me to see some colours when listing files.

And below are my prompt variables. The first one works fine for my user, and it is a ZSH edition of my `PS1` used in bash. The second one I didn't figure out yet, but in bash it was called `SUDO_PS1`.

```
export PROMPT="%F{blue}%m:%~ %F{green}$ %F{reset}"
# doesn't work:
# export SUDO_PS1="%F{red}%n@%m:%d %F{green}# %F{reset}"
```

Is there an equivalent for `SUDO_PS1` in ZSH? Or do I need to use `PROMPT` for both privilege levels?

I can't see my `PROMPT` as root. It is simply lost. How can I keep it in memory?

How can I enable colours for LS and other commands when I'm sudo-ing?

Comment: Just to be sure: The exact same `.zshrc` file resides in `/home/username` for your username and in `/root`? The one in `/root` belongs to the `root` user?

Comment: @Ned64 I have one in my local user dir, yes. I did add one for root (`/var/root`), but it seems to be ignored. As far as I understand, in bash, `SUDO_PS1` is used from my local user's profile, so every time I do `sudo su` I get that prompt. I wonder whether that's different for ZSH.